# python tkinter: how to iterate with rather specific times (root.after not working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

im writing an autoclicker. ive sperated my clicks by time between mouse down and mouse up, and time between clicks (those times are stored in a csv file). basic idea, i want to run the program, and a window pops up with a start and a stop button(accomplished). i want to be able to hit start, and run a 'loop' of clicks ('iterating' through a list with the times saved) until i hit pause. i say 'loop' and 'iterate' because i know you cant run a seperate loop inside the main loop of tkinter. i tried used root.after to wait the time between clicks, then call a function that performs a click, but root.after doesnt take times that are as specific as i want. any ideas? heres the full script, and ill give a sample of the csv file as well. Im open to using other modules besides tkinter/other languages, if anything pops into your mind

```
import csv
import time
from tkinter import *
from PyWinMouse import *


root = Tk()
start_button = Button(root, text="start", width="7")
pause_button = Button(root, text="pause", width="7")
start_button.pack()
pause_button.pack()

# holds times for clicks[time_between_up_down, time_between_clicks]
click_info = []
info_length = 0
clicker = Mouse()
paused = True
iterateVar = 0


def get_csv():
    global click_info, info_length
    file = open("times.csv", 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        click_info.append(row)
    info_length = len(click_info)


def click():
    global iterateVar
    if iterateVar < (info_length - 1) and paused is False:
        clicker.left_down()
        time.sleep(click_info[iterateVar][0])
        clicker.left_up()
        iterateVar += 1


def pause_button_function(event):
    global paused
    paused = True


def start_button_function(event):
    global paused
    paused = False


get_csv()
pause_button.bind("<Button-1>", pause_button_function)
start_button.bind("<Button-1>", start_button_function)
root.after(float(click_info[iterateVar][1]), click)
root.mainloop()
```

this error is given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File
"C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/NaturalHumanBehaviorClickInfoGatherer/ActualClic    ker.py", line 52, in <module>
    root.after(float(click_info[iterateVar][1]), click)
  File     "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",     line 604, in after
    return self.tk.call('after', ms, name)
_tkinter.TclError: bad argument "1.0223703384399414": must be cancel, idle,     info, or an integer
```

snapshot of what the csv file looks like(ignore the 'False', that's for other stuff):

```
0.0948493480682373,1.0223703384399414,False
0.09569144248962402,0.17647409439086914,False
0.06346511840820312,0.14343690872192383,False
0.09652972221374512,0.08008456230163574,False
0.07996273040771484,0.07998061180114746,False
0.09551239013671875,0.0805819034576416,False
0.08001160621643066,0.04780721664428711,False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after` method accepts time as  a integer form (in milliseconds). You need to convert the value into `int` (multiplied by 1000 to mean milliseconds):

```
ms = int(click_info[iterateVar][1] * 1000)
root.after(ms, click)
```

NOTE

1. `after` make the fucntion called once. If you want to call it repeatedly, you need to call it again (maybe inside the callback `click`).
2. Do not call `time.sleep` inside the callback function. It make UI freezing.